# How to synchronize perforce dev stream with mainline removing some changes that been already made in dev

Tags: perforce

I have 'mainline' stream and some 'dev' stream where I'm working.

I have the following scheme:

- create commit some changelists in 'dev'.
- create 'merge' changelist into 'mainline', and commit if after code review.

But what if I have changes in 'dev' stream that are not longer relevant, and I want them to be reversed in 'dev' stream to make it synchronized with 'mainline'.

Is it possible to create some changelist that would copy files from 'mainline' to 'dev' that would include changed files of 'dev'. (And I don't want to mess with 'mainline')

Answer (score 1):

In your dev stream, do:

```
p4 copy -F --from mainline
```

That will force a copy from the mainline, overwriting any changes in dev.

Comment: Thanks, actually I need it not for a whole stream but only for a files of some changelist I'd like to rollback, some I figured out I should use:

`p4 copy -f -F --from mainline actual_file_name.cpp`

Comment: If you want to roll back an individual changelist, an easier option is `p4 undo @CHANGELIST`.